# Как с помощь двумерного массива вывести цифры от 10 до 1?

Tags: c#, массивы

Написал код с помощью которого я могу вывести числа от 1 до 10. Что тут нужно исправить чтобы код выводил числа наоборот, от 10 до 1? И можно ли выводить только четные или нечетные числа?

```
int t, i;
int[,] table = new int[3, 4];
for (t = 0; t < 3; t++)
{
    for (i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        table[t, i] = (t * 4) + i + 1;
        Console.Write(table[t,i] + " ");
    }
    Console.WriteLine();
}
```

Comment: Можно цикл развернуть: ```for (t = 3; t > 0; t--)``` или на худой конец сделать так ```Console.Write((11-table[t,i]) + " ");``` а если серьезно - задача не требует объяснений, если конечно этот код вы написали сами в чем я сильно сомневаюсь :)

Comment: Сделайте заполнение массива отдельно от вывода в консоль.